# show hide content (wikipedia style)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a lot of titles on my page (h1) and I want to add a "show/hide" function just after each title in order to show the SPECIFIC content that follows, without having to add manualy an id for each content and title.

I'm pretty new to jquery and thats what I've done so far. As you'll notice, the problem is that every div is being showed/hiden.

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(&quot;h1&quot;).append(' [&lt;a class=&quot;show-hide&quot;&gt;Show/Hide&lt;/a&gt;]');
  $(&quot;.show-hide&quot;).click(function(){
    $(&quot;div&quot;).slideToggle(&quot;normal&quot;);
  })
});
```

And the HTML code:

```
<h1>Title 1</h1>
<div>Content 1</div>
<h1>Title 2</h1>
<div>Content 2</div>
<h1>Title 3</h1>
<div>Content 3</div>
```

And it woul look like this:

```
Title 1 [Show/Hide]
Content 1
Title 2 [Show/Hide]
Content 2
Title 3 [Show/Hide]
Content 3
```

Comment: Why are you typing `&quot;` instead of `"`?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
   $("h1").append(' [<a class="show-hide">Show/Hide</a>]');
   $(".show-hide").click(function(){
      $("div").slideToggle("normal");
   })
});`

Comment: And how does this answer my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('h1').click(function (e) {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxExj/).

Click on any h1 tag to see it in action ;)

Comment: +1 Wow, that's pretty clean :).  Only criticism I have is that if content is added later, between the title and content divs, this will break.  I would give the content divs and title divs ids or classes then use a selector as next's parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not exactly what I'm looking for. Have a look a this codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ivGHK